# what are processing options on magento, while checkout process

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have confronted this requirement of selecting `Processing` methods `standard`, `quick` and `rush` while checkout just before selecting shipping methods.

[image]

And i couldn't even figure out what this is called, how this functionality is achieved or what sort of modules are available for this if any.

I know it might be out of track question to ask for, but i couldn't even search for this as i am unknown and has just encountered this. So please don't mark this as negative question as there is no other place to find this information other than this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Usually delivery time would be included in the shipping method step. For each **shipping method** there can be multiple **rates**, returned by the collectRates() method of each shipping method. Try too hook in your additional processing cost there.

Adding a new step in the checkout is possible too but more complicated, needs rewrite of core classes and the checkout related Javascript objects in opcheckout.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new step to checkout [here](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/10/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step/) you'll find how to do it.

Alternatively you can too add a custom form to your shipping method and handle the selection logic with JS, [here](http://tutorialsformagento.blogspot.in/2014/06/add-custom-fields-to-order-and-quote.html) is an example of how to add a custom template for shipping method.